# Loopback remote call on downloading file

Tags: strongloop, loopback

Is it possible to add a remote method call like afterRemote/beforeRemote while download call of a file in loopback?

File model has a base class to "model",
Has operations like upload,download, by using container and file name as parameters.
On that, while using downloading file using the above instance, need to log a record into a table. For this need to trigger a after Remote function call. Is this possible while downloading a file as a GET method

Comment: Your question needs more info. What do you mean by "while download call of a file"?

Comment: Yes, you can. It is like any remote method

Comment: E.g.I used code like this, Post.afterRemote('download',function(ctx,model,next{//some code}),but can't get into this method, can any one get sorted out this.?

Comment: Please mention me to be notified you commented to me. The general is that if you call callback you can use remote hooks. So would you mind show `download` method code?